# Hybris component in Addon not calling controller

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I created my custom form component. After I added it in the smart edit, it doesn't call controller to fillIn the form.
I created itemtype *MyComponentModel* in *-items.xml, checked in HAC deployment, it's there. 
I also added annotations like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37963140/2966401)

```
@Controller("MyComponentController")
@RequestMapping(value = ControllerConstants.Actions.Cms.MyComponent)
public class MyComponentController extends AbstractAcceleratorCMSComponentController<MyComponentModel> {
```

and the mapping value is in my ControllerConstants like this:

```
String _Prefix = "/view/"; // NOSONAR
String _Suffix = "Controller"; // NOSONAR
String MyComponent = _Prefix + MyComponentModel._TYPECODE + _Suffix; // NOSONAR
```

When I add it in smartedit on a page, the .jsp file is loaded (I can see some text), but as the controller isn't called

According to Hybris doc, the called method in my controller should be this:

```
@Override
protected void fillModel(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, MyComponentModel component) {
```

But it isn't called, so I'm not able to fill the form.

```
<div class="span-20 last">
    I can see this text
    <div class="row item_container_holder">
        <c:if test="${not empty MyForm}">
          <%--this condition is false, form is empty--%>
```

Note that I also added component in impex, I have updated system in HAC, I tried to sync catalogs.

```
INSERT_UPDATE MyComponent; $contentCV[unique = true]; uid[unique = true]       ; name                               ; &componentRef
;; MyComponent ; MyComponent ; MyComponent
```

EDIT:

*-items.xml

```
 <itemtype code="MyComponent" autocreate="true" generate="true" extends="SimpleCMSComponent"
              jaloclass="mypackage.b2c.core.jalo.components.MyComponent">
        <deployment table="MyComponents" typecode="15900"/>
        <attributes>
            <attribute qualifier="title" type="localized:java.lang.String">
                <persistence type="property" />
                <modifiers />
                <description>Localized title of the component.</description>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </itemtype>
```

Comment: add your *items.xml for MyComponentModel. First, your Impex seems wrong here

Comment: Are you trying to create this coponent in your Addon? If yes, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035370/jsp-controller-not-found-for-custom-component-in-hybris-addon/52035785#52035785)

Comment: I edited an impex. Yes, it's my addon. Now it's calling the controller, but it can not find a .jsp file. I put it on path `/WEB-INF/views/responsive/cms`, but I still get an error `Error processing component tag. currentComponent [MyComponentModel (8796093136412@1)] exception: File [/WEB-INF/views/responsive/cms/myComponent.jsp] not found`

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you are trying to create this component in the addon

Make sure you followed the step I have mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035370/jsp-controller-not-found-for-custom-component-in-hybris-addon/52035785#52035785)

> **Your comment:** I put it on path `/WEB-INF/views/responsive/cms`, but I still get an
>   error Error processing component tag. currentComponent
>   [MyComponentModel (8796093136412@1)] exception: `File
>   [/WEB-INF/views/responsive/cms/myComponent.jsp] not found`

Debug **getView** method of **AbstractCMSAddOnComponentController** to check the path.

You have to add your jsp to `/youraddon/acceleratoraddon/web/webroot/WEB-INF/views/responsive/cms/myComponent.jsp`, which later will be copied to your stroefront extension while build process.

Answer (score 1):

The controller called for a cms component depends on the itemtype. You cannot create a JspIncludeComponent and expect a component controller for MyComponent to get called.

Try this instead:

```
INSERT_UPDATE MyComponent;...
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but how can I define a path to my .jsp file? I've put it to path `/WEB-INF/views/responsive/cms`, but it still gets me an error `Error processing component tag. currentComponent [MyComponentModel (8796093136412@1)] exception: File [/WEB-INF/views/responsive/cms/myComponent.jsp] not found` but I can see that file there.

Comment: Consider this class: de.hybris.training.storefront.controllers.cms.AbstractAcceleratorCMSComponentController the getView method describes how a view is resolved for a cms component.

Comment: In your case that should be WEB-INF/views/desktop/cms/mycomponent.jsp. Depending on the experience level set you have to use the responsive or mobile folder instead of desktop.

Comment: In general they should be in "WEB-INF/views/desktop/cms/" + the lowercase name of your component + jsp.

Comment: For components in addons it's a bit more tricky. Your Controller needs to extend de.hybris.platform.addonsupport.controllers.cms.GenericCMSAddOnComponentController. The superclass method getView in de.hybris.platform.addonsupport.controllers.cms.AbstractCMSAddOnComponentController then determines the view. Put you jsp file in myaddon/web/webroot/WEB-INF/views/desktop/cms/ with the same lowercase name.

Comment: The build process will then copy it to your storefront extension to this folder: WEB-INF/views/addons/myaddon/desktop/cms/. The View Resolver de.hybris.training.storefront.web.view.UiExperienceViewResolver will then do some string magic to replace the view name with the path in your storefront directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check extending class. Could be "Accelerator" is extra in AbstractAcceleratorCMSComponentController